# Laravel- How to pass two values to controller from datatable using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatable

I want to pass tow variables from datatable to controller using ajax, I want to pass the current id, and the current vendro_id if its exist!
I want to pass varaible on exit of the vendor_id input as shown in screen shot
[image: screenshot]

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
       var oTable = $('#users-table').DataTable({
            dom: 'flBrtip',
               processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                 url: 'custom-filter-data',
         columns : [
         {data: 'id'},  
         {data: 'details', name: 'details'},
          {data: 'description', name: 'description'},
         {data: 'vendor_id',render: function (data) {        
           return ('<label hidden>'+data+'</label> <input type="text" id="vendor" class="vendor" onClick="this.select();" value="'+data+'">');   
           }}, 
             ],
         pageLength: 10,
        };
    oTable.draw();
   </script>
```

I know how to pass variables form input fields but don't know how to pass from datatable it doesnt work for passing two varaibles

```
    $( "#vendor" ).on('blur', function() { 
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Vendor_Save',
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
             'currentid': {data: 'id'},
             'current_vendor_id': {data: 'vendor_id'},

        },
        success: function(data) {
             console.log(data);
            }
          });

              });
```

Comment: didn't get your question can you explain whats your problem , you want to pass two variable from data table to controller using ajax

Comment: yes, that is it! its clear I want only to pass id variable and vendor id of the current row, and this only must implement and excute when exit the input of vendor _id which has the id vendor! I think my question is very clear